# Search for a word in column and then copy row

Tags: excel, copy

I have two tabs -  the ALL tab and CATA tab.

ALL tab has all the data (source)
CATA tab is the target tab where specific rows have to be pasted.

Question:

- I want to search all rows one by one,
- then copy rows from source tab where the column I has CATA word in it
- and then paste that row to the target tab.

Sample data for column I:

```
"USTA;#CATA;#INTA;#Non-TA"
"USTA;#INTA;#Non-TA"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an approach as described below:

1. Insert a filter on the whole table, and filter on column I on `Text` > `Contains` and type "CATA" in the entry box.
2. Copy everything except column A then paste in the tab `CATA`.

Comment: Isn't the `CATA` keyword only in column I? In which case, couldn't you just filter on column I for `*CATA*` and then do the copy/pasting?

Comment: @tigeravatar For some reason, I think I didn't see the `I` in the question at all and thought the keyword could be in any column in the table.........

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows that match is unknown and you don't want blank rows in between, this will produce a subset of the rows that contain the phrase "CATA" in Column A.

This is the formula for cell A2 that can be dragged down as far as needed:

```
=IFERROR(
  INDEX(ALL!A:A,
    SMALL(
      IF(
        NOT(ISERROR(FIND("CATA",ALL!A:A))),
        ROW(ALL!A:A)),
      ROW()-ROW($A$1))),"")
```

It must be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

It will display a blank row once all the possible CATA rows have been found.

For Column B, it changes only by two references (A:A becomes B:B):

```
=IFERROR(
  INDEX(ALL!B:B,
    SMALL(
      IF(
        NOT(ISERROR(FIND("CATA",ALL!A:A))),
        ROW(ALL!B:B)),
      ROW()-ROW($A$1))),"")
```

You may replicate this for as many columns as need to be transferred. Don't forget to start entering it in Row 2, and be sure to enter the first one with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER before dragging it down the column.

Comment: None of thesolution above is working out, I have pasted the code that I am using, can you help me to insert logic to "search for CATA in Col I" and if it finds then "copy row", and then paste it in CATA sheet.

Comment: Code that I am using rite now: Sub Entity()

Dim r As Range, c As Range

Worksheets("cata").Cells.Clear
With Worksheets("all")

Set r = Range(.Range("K2"), .Range("K2").End(xlDown))

For Each c In r


If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(c) Then
   
   Range(.Cells(c.Row, "A"), .Cells(c.Row, "O")).Copy

Else
    GoTo nextc
End If


With Worksheets("cata")
     .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
End With

nextc:

Next c

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Comment: @user2805208 you should edit your question to include that code.  Also, the code is only looking for numbers in column K.  Do you want to replace that search with the search for `*CATA*` in column I? Or do you want to adjust the code to match both conditions (numbers in column K AND `*CATA*` in column I)?  Either way, please update and clarify your question